# TypeScript custom type hint

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-generics

I would like to declare few simple types, to distinguish strings like "url", "absolute url", "json", etc. It would be enough, to show declared type in hint, but type checking would be even better (i.e. "url" couldn't be passed to function expecting "absolute url").

The issue is that TypeScript/VSC understands, that "url" is a string and skips my declared type. Is there any way, to show declared type in hint? I don't mind hacky solutions as long as they don't break TypeScript features.

Sample code - I want to see "const data: url" in hint:

[image]

What I want to see (but this solution is bad, because url shouldn't be a number):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

Intersect your primitive type with an empty object type.

```
type url = string & {};
```

**Explanation**

Note that `{}` does not mean *empty object* as you may think. It represents everything but `null | undefined`. Here, mixing `string` with `{}` doesn't change anything, but the name will now be preserved.

Comment: Thank you for solution and explanation - I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a hack to achieve something you've asked for using primitive types.
But don't you mind using `enum`?

As a pros you will have your Url's in one place.

[image]

Comment: This is a nice idea, but unfortunately won't cover all my cases, i.e. getting data from API. Thank you for it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that your type aliases get preserved as typescript does not care if something is a `string` or a `url` as they have the same underlying type. This is due to the [structural (as opposed to nominal)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) typing philosophy typescript adopts, although there are some proposals to support this use case (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33038, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33290).

Your best bet in the mean time is to use a function with a return type like so:

[image: working code]

As for your other question - different url types - you can achieve something like this using [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) & adding properties to the `string` object:

```js
type url = string & { _subtype: 'absoluteUrl' | 'relativeUrl' | 'other' }
type absoluteUrl = url & { _subtype: 'absoluteUrl' }
type relativeUrl = url & { _subtype: 'relativeUrl' }

const createAbsoluteUrl = (input: string) => {
  const createdAbsoluteUrl = input
  ;(createdAbsoluteUrl as any)._subtype = 'absoluteUrl'
  return createdAbsoluteUrl as absoluteUrl
}

const createRelativeUrl = (input: string) => {
  const createdRelativeUrl = input
  ;(createdRelativeUrl as any)._subtype = 'relativeUrl'
  return createdRelativeUrl as relativeUrl
}

const expectAbsoluteUrl = (input: absoluteUrl) => {
  // something
}

const expectRelativeUrl = (input: relativeUrl) => {
  // something
}
```

You should then see type errors as you expect:
[image]

You may also find [user defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) useful if you go with this approach

Comment: This answer is great and covers also typechecks, so thank you very much for your help. There is one big drawback for me - functions would be compiled into JS and performance would suffer a little bit, so I will go with solution from Karol Majewski.